# optgroup generated by php

Tags: php, html, optgroup

I'm trying to generate optgroups and options with PHP from an array, and it generates it, but my optgroup is wrong. It display only the first word. In the page source it's correct.

```
$my_array = array(
    first optgroup => array(
        key1 =>value1,
        key2 => value2,
        key3 => value3,
    ),
    second optgroup => array(
        key1 =>value1,
        key2 => value2,
        key3 => value3,
    ),
);
foreach ($my_array as $optgroup => $other_array) {
    echo "<optgroup label=". $optgroup . ">";

    foreach ($other_array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<option value=" . $key . ">" . $value . "</option>";
}
    echo "</optgroup>";

in the source code is fine:

<optgroup label=first optgroup>
    <option value=key1>value1</option>
    <option value=key2>value2</option> 
    .......
```

but on my select box I see only "first", instead of "first optgroup"

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to embed some quotes:

```
echo "<optgroup label=\"{$optgroup}\">";
                      ^^-----------^^----
```

Note the backslash escapes on the embedded quotes. This'll generate

```
<optgroup label="foo bar">
```

instead of the

```
<optgroup label=foo bar> 
                ^^^--- value for "label" attribute
                    ^^^---unknown random attribute
```

you're doing now

Comment: The option with better performance would be `echo ´<optgroup label="',$optgroup,'">';`

Comment: if the microscopic savings of using `,` instead of a concatenated string save your system, then you're working on a facebook-sized operation, and shouldn't be asking simple questions like this on this site.

Comment: Just pointing out. At your request, I can remove the comment. And facebook is a terrible example, since their performance is quite dubious... The website is slow as a snail race in slow-motion.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$my_array = array(
    'first optgroup' => array(
        'key1' =>'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
        'key3' => 'value3',
    ),
    'second optgroup '=> array(
        'key1' =>'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
        'key3' => 'value3',
    ),
);

echo "<select>";
foreach ($my_array as $optgroup => $other_array) {
    echo "<optgroup label=". $optgroup . ">";
    foreach ($other_array as $key => $value) 
        echo "<option value=" . $key . ">" . $value . "</option>";
}
    echo "</optgroup>";
});
echo "</select>";
```